# How to edit "mexopt.bat" file in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, opencv, viola-jones

I have Matlab R2014b and OpenCV 2.4, i have been trying to use ViolaJones Face Detection toolbox, but i have some troubles. I've searhced the problem and found a solution that suggest edit `mexopt.bat` file. What the real problem is here

The Matlab command

```
fullfile(prefdir, 'mexopts.bat')
```

returns

> C:\Users\simit\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2014b\mexopts.bat

but I can't find the file when I go to the path. How can I find the `mexopts.bat` file and edit it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have R2015b installed. I searched my computer for a `mexopts.bat` file, and found it in folders related to code I have from 2012-2013, but not in the new MATLAB install folder. For this reason I believe it's not a part of the standard MATLAB installation, which is probably why you didn't find it.

According to [this thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/67521-32bit-and-64bit-compilations#comment_216789) it seems that the `mexopts.bat` file is no longer used in MATLAB starting R2014a, and instead you should look for these files:

```
mex_C_win32.xml
mex_C_win64.xml
MBUILD_C_win32.xml
MBUILD_C_win64.xml
```

---

If you are still convinced that you should find and edit a `mexopts` file, let me recommend you the [Everything Search Engine](http://www.voidtools.com/) to look for files on your hard-drive.

Comment: I really thank you for your recommendation @Dev-iL, i tried "Everything Search Engine" and couldn't find. But as you mentioned, i must rearrange .xml files instead of mexopt.bat file or i can change the version of Matlab.